# AngularJS - Add DOM elements on counter++

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation

I'm quite new to AngularJS and have read a little bit about how `directives` work. I'm still not quite sure about how to go about this problem though.

Here's the setup:

I have buttons on a view like so:

```
<div class="parent">
  <button class="firstButton" type="button" ng-click="fetchData(param1, param2)"></button>
  <button class="secondButton" type="button" ng-click="fetchData(param1, param2)"></button>
  <button class="thirdButton" type="button" ng-click="fetchData(param1, param2)"></button>
  <button class="fourthButton" type="button" ng-click="fetchData(param1, param2)"></button>
</div>
<div class="dataPanel">

 <!-- This is where DIVs will be placed -->

</div>
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
// Init value of counter here
var counter = 0;

$scope.fetchData = function (param1, param2) {

  // Do something with parameters here

  counter++;
}
```

**Ideal scenario** would be when user clicks on `firstButton`, `fetchData()` initiates, getting data from a factory, then increments value of `counter`. A div would be created from `counter` value change. The number of divs created in the DOM would depend on `counter` value. Each created div is also populated with data gotten from each respective `fetchData()`. This goes on as user clicks on more buttons, although in my current project, I've limited the number of allowed `dataSet` duplicates.

End result of the HTML would then be:

```
<div class="dataPanel">
 <div class="dataSet">  <!-- from firstButton -->
  <p>{{dataFromFirstButton}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class="dataSet">  <!-- from secondButton -->
  <p>{{dataFromSecondButton}}</p>
 </div>
 <div class="dataSet">  <!-- from thirdButton-->
  <p>{{dataFromThirdButton}}</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

What's the **Angular way** of doing this? I've read directives can pretty much do everything when it comes to DOM manipulation but have no idea on where to start when it comes to actually constructing the directive.

Comment: What if the first button is clicked twice, should that create two divs? Or should there only be one div created per button?

Comment: simplify this down to one button  and one output list for now. Use `ng-repeat` and the various filters it exposes for your data. Once you get that working start modularizing to directive. You seem to be trying too much at once and need to get some familiarity with how angular works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use ng-repeat directive to draw the divs based on an array, that is initially empty. You can set the html up so that a div is drawn for each object in the array, since the array is empty no div is initially drawn.

```
<div class="dataSet" ng-repeat="n in arrays[0]">
  This div from button 1 contains: {{n.data}}
</div>
```

When you click on the buttons you can add an object, containing any needed data, to the array. Then a div will be drawn for the appropriate ng-repeat directive.

```
  $scope.arrays = [ [], [], [], []];

  $scope.fetchData = function (data, idx) {
    $scope.arrays[idx].push({data: data});
  }
```

See [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rr3eVk60j9CWT0RhOVyq).